# Como obtener datos del usuario logueado con axios en vuejs y laravel auth

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

estoy arrancando mi camino con VueJS y quiero obtener los datos del usuario actualmente logeado en el sistema en un archivo .vue, queria hacer la request en un archivo .js que tengo aparte que realiza las peticiones para un checkout...
Desde este ultimo archivo javascript realizo tambien la peticion para obtener la data de la carta que esta armando el usuario en el momento, como tambien necesitaria obtener los datos de este mismo. Esto mismo se hacerlo atraves del controlador con Auth::user(), pero el tema es que necesito los datos en mi archivo .vue para completar los campos de el sdk de paypal el cual lo renderizo desde aqui, desde el .vue file... Aqui dejo parte de mi codigo

**index.js (archivo js)**

```
import { ref } from "vue";

export default function usePayP() {

const products = ref([]);
const usuar = ref();

const getProducts = async() => {
    let response = await axios.get('/api/products');
    
    products.value = response.data.cartContent;
}

const getUser = async() => {
    axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');
    axios.get('/api/user').then((response)=>{

        usuar.value = response.data.usuar;
      })//esta es la funcion que necesito que me devuela la data de user
}

 return {
     products,
     getProducts,
     getUser,
     usuar
 }
}
```

**checkout.vue (archivo vueJS)**

```
<template>

<div>
{{users_i_want}
</div>

<div id="paypal-button-container" class="paypal-button-container"></div>

</template>

<script setup>

import { onMounted, computed } from 'vue';
import usePayP from "../composables/checkout";

const {
    products,
    getProducts,
    getUser,
    usuar
} = usePayP();


const users_i_want = computed(() => {
    let asd = Object.values(usuar.value);

    return asd;
});


onMounted(async() => {
    await getProducts();
    await getUser();
})
```

**api.php (rutas)**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\CartController;


Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->group(function () {

  Route::get('/user', function(Request $request){
      return $request->user();
  }); 

  Route::get('products/increase/{id}', [CartController::class, 'increase']);
  Route::get('products/decrease/{id}', [CartController::class, 'decrease']);

  Route::get('products/count', [CartController::class, 'count'])->name('products.count');

  Route::apiResource('products', CartController::class);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const getUser = async () => {

  try {
    await axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');
    const response = await axios.get('/api/user')
    usuar.value = response.data;
  }//esta es la funcion que necesito que me devuela la data de user
  catch (error) { 
    //
  }
}
```